# HTML5 how to draw transparent overlapping spheres?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-animation

I have a complex HTML5 task..
I need to draw transparent overlapping spheres. Please have a look at:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlw1Y.jpg

I need to draw a sphere which is easy, But, I need to fill it as it look in the picture above (link) and make sure its semi-transparent..

The spheres has to move, so, one time the smaller sphere in the back can be animated and be bigger..

I know its complicated (it looks easy but its hard to program).

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Here is example of Overlapping semitransparent Shapes on the Canvas http://ecommercedeveloper.com/articles/2908-drawing-basic-shapes-with-html5-canvas/

For animation and other things, just Google it, and code it step by step. Nobody will code everything to you if you didn't tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the globalAlpha value to get the transparency effect:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.globalAlpha = 0.5;
```

Something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zspxt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw transparent spheres use KineticJS:

http://jsfiddle.net/palani/mN2dC/